# .htaccess redirect exact page to non existent subdomain in laravel

Tags: .htaccess, laravel

I am building a website with laravel framework. 
i'm logging users in panel.domainname.com, but they also have public profile link. 
and i want to redirect exact link to public profile subdomain with htaccess file.

**for example:**

```
original link: http://panel.domainname.com/publicprofile/12-somename
redirected link: http://profile.domainname.com/publicprofile/12-somename
```

but profile subdomain is not defined.

Is it possible?
Thanks.

Comment: **Short answer: NO.** If there's no subdomain definition that can be validated via a DNS server, then there's no way to access it.

Comment: if there would be defined subdomain?